# How can I specify integer as a property or argument type in ColdFusion?

Tags: web-services, soap, types, coldfusion, wsdl

I'm building a WebService in ColdFusion 8 using CFCs with remote methods. I need to specify complex data types in the WSDL, so I'm creating CFCs for each of these types. For instance, let's say I have a "Person" type. It includes an "age" property. This property needs to always be an integer. However, ColdFusion does not have "integer" as a valid type - only Numeric, which translates to "xsd:double" in the WSDL. How can specify that a property - or an argument, for that matter - has a type of "integer"?

FYI, Henry's answer is very helpful, but I'm trying to return an Object from the function - not just an integer. I need one of the properties to be returned as an integer.

Comment: The mappings of built-in types for CF8 is here: http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=webservices_26.html, integer is not a valid type...but your question *seems* to imply that what you want are custom complex types, in which case you would add <CFPROPERTY> lines to your WebService CFC, and for their "type" attribute, you'd use your component (ie com.ericbelair.Person), and your method(s) would expect the entire object. Left as a comment because I'm unsure of the actual real question here.

Comment: I'm asking how I can make the CFPROPERTY declare a TYPE of integer. I thought there might be some way to invoke a Java class or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Write your own WSDL. Save your CFC and capture the RPC generated WSDL by pointing your browser at http://mysite/mypath/myCFC.cfc?WSDL
>      Grab the source, or clean up all the - added by your browser. Make
>      sure there is no white space before the `<?xml` version tag.
>      Find the `xsd:double` in the Response message and change it to `xsd:int`.
> 2. Specify the WSDL in your component. Add the `wsdlfile="mywsdl.wsdl"` attribute with the filename and add the attribute `style="document"`
>      which is required for user-defined WSDLs.
> 3. Bind the webservice to the WSDL ColdFusion does this automatically -- but it caches them. When a WSDL changes, you need to restart the service or go to "Data & Services -> Web Services" in CF
>      Administration and refresh the service.
> 4. Change your cffunction to return `"Any"` instead of `"Numeric"`
> 5. In your cfreturn, instantiate a Java Integer `<cfreturn createObject("java","java.lang.Integer").init(JavaCast("int",myvalue))`
>      />

http://www.threesources.com/archives/009007.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, how can I do this with a property of an Object that is being returned (see above)?